# Decorating the result of SparkContext textFile filtered lines

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

Using pyspark, I need to filter several daily access log files of an SNS service by user nos. And then, prettify the result by grouping it by user nos. Here is a part of python script that extracts user access log with an array of user nos:

```
def is_user_log(line):
    return any(userno in line for userno in userno_array)
sc = SparkContext(appName="<app_name>")
text_file = sc.textFile(hdfs_url)
lines = text_file.filter(is_user_log)
```

Now I've got the access logs that I am interested in by calling lines.collect(), but what I need to do here is to group the result by user nos. To be specific, when Spark catches the line that I'm interested, I want it to add some words into the line. Can it be possible using pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `map` transformation:

```
def extract_data(line):
    # here you write code to extract data
    # that may use regular expressions
    return line + extracted_data

lines.map(extract_data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But "some words" gotta be different line by line, e.g. the user no that the line is captured by.